# Can any pointer using malloc be considered an array?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

So, I am learning C right now, and wanted some clarification on some things.

I've learned that if we wanted to create a dynamic arrays we could use the following line of code:

```
int *arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

I understand that, in this case, arr is a pointer being allocated the equivalent of an array of 10 ints in terms of bytes. I also understand that you can treat arr as an array (from arr[0] to arr[9].

Does that mean all pointers that are allocated memory can be treated as an array?

Like could this be treated as an array?

```
int *single = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Or could this be treated as an array?

```
int *half = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1.5)
```

Comment: `int *single = malloc(sizeof(int));` corresponds to `int single[1];`. It can be used as `single[0]` or `*single`. `half` is also the same.

Comment: The second one would likely allocate 6 bytes, but you'd only be able to use it as an `int half[1]` array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; `malloc` expects it's argument to be of the type `size_t` and  `size_` is `unsigned` integer type. Shouldn't be passing a float to `malloc` (as in `malloc(sizeof(int) * 1.5)`) a constraint violation?

Comment: @haccks: Not if you've got a prototype in scope — the prototype ensures that the floating point value is converted to `size_t` before the call.  If you were careless enough to do without the prototype, you'd have trouble, but you woudn't be that silly, would you?  Prototypes are immensely important, and the fact that they ensure the conversion of arguments to the right type (if the conversion is possible) is one their benefits.  It's best not to pass a floating point value to `malloc()`, but with a prototype in scope, the value is converted to `size_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Ignoring the array size, yes all pointers can be used arrays (meaning you can index them).
- The number of elements should be an integer, with truncation for valid access (i.e., 1.5 means 1 item).
- You request number of bytes from malloc, it makes sense that this is a multiple of the item size.
- You should read about pointer arithmetic.
- Array names can also be used as pointers (e.g., *array) but you can't assign to them or modify them (e.g., ++array).

Answer (score 1):

> Like could this be treated as an array?
>
> ```
> int *single = malloc(sizeof(int));
> ```

Sure, it can be treated as an array `int single[1]`

> Or could this be treated as an array?
>
> ```
> int *half = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1.5)
> ```

Yes, but it will have the same effect as previous snippet but you will just waste 2 additional bytes. If you try to write in half[2], you can corrupt some memory.